# How to backslash a dynamic string in bash

Tags: bash, regular-expression, perl, escape-characters

I want to backslash a variable automatically so that the end users don't need to type the backslashes for a Perl regex string replacement.

```
API_URI="http://something/api"
FIND="(API_URI)(.*?[\=])(.*?[\'](.*?[\']))"
REPLACE="\\1\\2 \'$API_URI\'"
perl -pi -e "s/${FIND}/${REPLACE}/" file.ext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By all means use Perl if you want to, but doesn't this sed do the trick?

```
echo "$API_URI" | sed 's/\//\\\//g'
http:\/\/something\/api
```

Or... in straight Bash:

```
echo "${API_URI//\//\\/}"
http:\/\/something\/api
```

Comment: how to excape if there is also `.` in the url